# Pass string variable into paste R function with escaped double quotes

Tags: r, string

I need the exact same output from this line of code,

```
> paste('"a"','"b"')
[1] "\"a\" \"b\""
```

but I need "b" to be a variable which changes in each iteration, so suppose I have `x <-"b", paste('"a"',x)` or any other ways I tried failed to give me the output I wanted, which is

```
> paste('"a"','"b"')
[1] "\"a\" \"b\""
```

Thanks in advance!

OM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using `sprintf`

```
x <- "b"
sprintf('"a" "%s"', x)
# [1] "\"a\" \"b\""
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a variable then you have to manually surround it with double quotes. You can use an extra call to paste to do that

```
> x <- "b"
> paste('"a"', paste('"', x, '"', sep=''))
[1] "\"a\" \"b\""
```

Comment: In recent versions of R, you could shorten this to `x <- "b"; paste('"a"', paste0('"', x, '"'))`

Answer (score 2):

There must be a better way to it, but this works:

```
x<-paste0('"',"b",'"',collapse = "")

paste('"a"',x)
[1] "\"a\" \"b\""
```

Comment: The `collapse = ""` is redundant here.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this with a function would be:

```
quote_me <- function(...) paste0('"', unlist(list(...)), '"')
x <- "b"
quote_me("a", b)
#[1] "\"a\"" "\"b\""
```